# android startactivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application that contains 3 activities A, B and C. The activity A is the one that gets started when I start my app. From A I start B using `mIntent.setClass(A.this, B.class);`, then `startActivity(mIntent);` this goes well. What goes wrong is when I want to start the activity C from B.

this how the manifestfile looks like:

```
    <activity android:name=".B"/>
    <activity android:name=".C"/>
```

I know that I can do the follwoings: start B from A and then from B go back to A and then start C

or let B has its own manifestfile thus a stand lone app, and let C be an activity within this app.

Any suggestion is welcome. My apoligies for my bad english.

thank you

Comment: I don't get it.  What is that actual problem with you you try to start Activity C from B?  What is the code you use to do so, and what are the errors/behavior?

Comment: yes you are right I want to start B from C. I use this:
mIntent.setClass(B.this, C.class);
startActivity(mIntent);

the error is:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1804): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1804): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.aapA/test.aapA.B}: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1804):     at test.aapA.B.startC(B.java:40)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1804):     at test.aapA.B.onCreate(B.java:29)

sorry there was some incorrect code in my orriginal post

Comment: Why do you want to start a new activity in onCreate?

Comment: the issue is not where I want to start a new activity. Try to start the activity C by pressing a button the same issue occures.

Comment: post your code and the corresponding logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you posted in the comments is a NullPointerException which means some variable you're calling a method on (or attempting to access a property of, etc) has not yet been instantiated.  Is it possible that you're declaring mIntent but not setting it to a new Intent before calling setClass?  Post the code for class B, and it should be pretty easy to figure out (NullPointerExceptions usually are).

Comment: agreed, if we could see the code for your B.onCreate and B.startC, you might be mission an initialization.

Answer (score 1):

mIntent goes null if you don't get it in your B activity.
So inside B, you shloud initialize mIntent.

You can do this for instance

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, C.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing this in onCreate, did you call super.onCreate before (attempting to) starting this new Activity?

Comment: yes. but as I said the issue is not where I start the activity C. thank you